# Is there any File Manager Module for drupal 7

Tags: 7, files

I need a module as like as File manager. We need to view, edit, modify and delete the files and also with permission option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many modules available for managing files.

Reference URL : https://drupal.org/module-categories/file-management

Try this module : https://drupal.org/project/elfinder i think it suits your requirement.

Comment: will try to enable that module it throws like "elFinder library was not found. Please download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/elfinder/files/ and install to . (Currently using elFinder Not found)".

Comment: will download from mentioned path but no use it display as same

Comment: After downloading elfinder files have you placed it in sites/all/libraries folder ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most robust file manager is Plupload. It does indeed have permissions that can be set. You can add functionality to it such as unzipping and selecting multiple files.

https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload